# How to expand the outliner's hierarchy to show the active object with python

Tags: outliner

I've built a nif importer plugin and I want to expand the outliner (if there's one showing) to reveal the newly imported objects. The following snippet does what I want if I run it from a text window:

```
        for area in [a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == 'OUTLINER']:
        for region in [r for r in area.regions if r.type == 'WINDOW']:
            override = {'area':area, 'region': region}
            bpy.ops.outliner.show_active(override)
```

But if I run the same code from my importer, it has no affect.

Does anyone know why not? Note I'm using bpy.context, not the context given to the importer because I figure I want to change what the user sees, but using the importer's context doesn't change the behavior.

I know we're supposed to use temp_override() these days, but that doesn't change the behavior either.